# .NET Runtime 2.0 Error in a windows application

Tags: .net, runtime

I have a Windows chat application that uses XMPP protocol. My problem is that, when the program in running on our testing machine, it gets closed intermittently. In the 'Application Log' in 'Event Viewer', I found,

> Faulting application MyApp.exe, version 1.0.0.0, stamp 4e4130e9, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.

but could not diagnose what is the actual problem. I found many similar error on searching, but mine is a Windows application and all the discussed errors are related to IIS.

How can I diagnose and solve the problem?

Comment: How exactly do you know this is a .NET Runtime error? Looks like a kernel32 error to me.

Comment: why do you think the error is with .NET 2? which framework version are you targeting? does anything change if you target a newer Framework version? can you describe your application a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that machine have problems with the installation of the .NET Framework (for example only .NET Framework 4.0 which is incompatible with applications for older versions is installed) or the .NET Framework is not installed at all.

Comment: The .NET framework is *almost always* backwards compatible with older .NET runtimes. `The .NET Framework 4 is highly compatible with applications that are built with earlier .NET Framework version`

Comment: I have .Net framework installed in that system. In the Application Log in Event Viewer I am seeing .Net 2.0 Run time error .  How can I fix if this is a kernal32 error?